# More questions about Javascript classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tested quite a bit about making classes, now I finally discovered how it works, that's what I want to make class simple and clear, without spamming 'this'

[image]

The result is like that, now I only have 2 questions:

1. `redsheep.options.show().sizes`, is to call out this variable, now I think it is *too long*. How do I make it like `redsheep.sizes`?
2. `redsheep.options.show().eat` is not inherit from the `sheepclass` `grass`, and became `undefined`. How do I make default values for newly created objects?

   ```
   <html>
   <head>
   <meta charset='utf-8'>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <title>A simple javascript function</title>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function(){
           var sheepclass = function(options){
               this.options = {'sizes' : 'thin',
                       'eat'   : 'grass',
                       'color' : 'white',
                       show    : function(){
                                   return {'color':options.color,
                                            'eat':options.eat,
                                            'sizes':options.sizes
                                           };
                                }
                }
           }

           var blacksheep = new sheepclass({'color':'black'});
           var redsheep   = new sheepclass({'color':'red','sizes':'fat'});

           $('div').append('<p>blackcsheep color : ' +
                           blacksheep.options.show().color);
           $('div').append('<p>redsheep color : ' + 
                           redsheep.options.show().color +
                           '<p>redsheep size:' +
                           redsheep.options.show().sizes +
                           '<p> redsheep eat:' + 
                           redsheep.options.show().eat);
       })
   </script>
   <style>
       div{display:block;width:800px;height:400px;border:2px solid red;}
   </style>
   </head>
   <body>
       <div>
             Result:
       </div>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

Comment: You realise you forgot a ; at the end of your document.ready? Not sure if it makes any difference but try adding that ;)

Comment: js does not need ; in the end :)

Comment: You paste your entire HTML document here, yet you complain `redsheep.options.show().sizes` is TOO LONG?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a method to an object that returns its own properties is useless. Remove that and access the properties normally:

```
var sheepclass = function(options) {
    this.options = $.extend({
        'sizes': 'thin',
        'eat': 'grass',
        'color': 'white',
    }, options);
}
```

You can access it like this:

```
redsheep.options.eat
```

Comment: so $.extend is a keyword that can't be change?

Comment: @FatDogMark `$.extend` is a method of the jQuery object that merges two hashmaps.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that would do:

```
var sheepclass = function(options) {
    this.sizes = options.sizes || 'thin';
    this.eat = options.eat || 'grass';
    this.color = options.color || 'white';
}
```

That way, you can access properties directly (by using for example `blacksheep.sizes`):

```
var blacksheep = new sheepclass({'color':'black'});
console.log(blacksheep.sizes); // prints 'thin'
```